Random screen dragging and desktop icon flashing on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I recently did a fresh install of 24.04 LTS on a used thinkpad that had windows on it. For some reason I keep getting a very odd behavior that's a bit hard to describe.

If I'm on my desktop screen, then it looks like the screen/icons are being dragged up a bit and no mouse or keyboard clicks work anymore.
If I'm on any app screen, then either the app window randomly becomes smaller OR more frequently I just start seeing icons from my desktop appear and then disappear many times. In this case no mouse or keyboard clicks work anymore either.

In both cases the only way I can get it to stop is by either pressing the escape key or logging out with ctrl + alt + delete. Sometimes this behavior doesn't happen for a few hours but sometimes it happens frequently, like every 30 seconds or so.
One thing I tried was disabling the trackpad and using a mouse, but the issue still remains.
Edit: a few more things that might be relevant:

My screen is a touch screen, though I don't really use that feature
Sometimes some app windows randomly resize
Today my mouse randomly started flickering and I couldn't click anywhere until I logged out and logged in again

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance!
